# Ensure HTTPS connection using express.js and Google Cloud

Tags: express, https, gcloud

Some API endpoints in my application require HTTPS connection.

I am trying to enforce that by using the following express.js code:

```js
  if (!req.connection.encrypted) {
    return res.status(401).json({errors: [{code: 'INSECURE_REQUEST', message: 'Reseller API requires HTTPS'}]})
  }
```

But the `req.secure` constantly returns `false` on Google Cloud.
Is there any kind of request forwarding that doesn't forward HTTPS internally inside Google Cloud? Is there any other way to ensure HTTPS connection inside express application on Google Cloud?

Comment: If your application is running behind a proxy server, you can use the standard "x-forwarded-proto" header to find out if the original request was https or http.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to ensure HTTPS traffic in the App Engine Standard is to add `secure: always` element for each handler in your app.yaml file.

If you're using a flexible environment, you have 2 options depending if you are using a custom domain or not.

If not, you can replace the actual dot in your url with -dot-. More info [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/application-security#https_requests).

If you are using a custom domain, you can see the whole process [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl).

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Doc contains an answer: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#https_and_forwarding_proxies

> App Engine terminates the HTTPS connection at the load balancer and forwards the request to your application. Some applications need to determine the original request IP and protocol. The user's IP address is available in the standard X-Forwarded-For header. Applications that require this information should configure their web framework to trust the proxy.
>
> With Express.js, use the trust proxy setting:
>
> ```
> app.set('trust proxy', true);
> ```